# Installing package "sf" in R; in macOS 10.13.2 error: ...anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-gfortran: No such file or directory

Tags: r, macos-sierra, r-sf

I am trying to download "sf" package and it is [generating an error][1] for me on mac os 10.13.2. Please note, I have also downloaded Xcode app. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, Anaconda was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use anaconda R, use CRAN R.